# Flatlist React native card's onPress does not trigger on Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist, touchableopacity

I am using `Expo` for my app. I have a horizontal Flatlist where I render my data  `react native paper's` Card. I saw Card have onPress function. I used that to navigate the another page. But onPress function does not trigger on Android device.  I know React native's touchable-opacity have  positioning issue on Android. I tried `hitSlop` and inline styling `zIndex` but still does not work. I also wrap my card with `react-native's` touchable-opacity and play with positioning still did not help me, only it works when i used `react-native-gesture-handler's` touchable-opacity but then it does not work on IOS. Hope anyone can help me...

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

interface Iprops {
  item: string;
}

export default function RenderCard({ item }: Iprops) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <Card
      hitSlop={{ "bottom": 30, "top": 30, "right": 30, "left": 30 }}
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate(`detail`, { // THIS DOES NOT TRIGGER ON ANDROID 
          "id": `${item.pk}`
        });
      }}
      style={{ "marginBottom": 20 }}>
      <Card.Cover
        source={{ "uri": `${item.img_url}` }} />
      <Card.Actions>
        <Card.Title title={item.name} subtitle="Card Subtitle" />
      </Card.Actions>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that using onPressIn or onPressOut does work on Android within an absolute positioned flatlist, but onPress does not work. I hope this might be of help to someone out there looking for an answer.

You'll need to use the TouchableOpacity element from react-native-gesture-handler.

Answer (score 0):

Like you told, you should add touchable opacity to the element you are rendering on the card. TouchableOpacity can be tricky. So, first give it a styling of borderWidth:1 and borderColor to see the actual touchable area on the screen. Then you start to bring them together with the icon or the image or whatever you are rendering. TouchableOpacity works but the positioning can be tricky. You have to understand it to use it better. Think touchableOpacity as a view with borders then it'll be easier to grasp. Also, if you dont give touchableOpacity an absolute position in the styling it will be out of the screen somewhere, I was never be able to bring it to somewhere that I can see to position it. So you can add `'position'` as well.

Comment: Position: `absolute` can't be my option then it will make mess my whole app's `UI`.

Comment: @Krisna use the Dimensions module from react-native to get the devices width & height. So that you can use those values dynamically to position those exceptional elements.

Comment: which style's I should use Dimensions' width and height

Comment: @Krisna you can use the Dimensions module to get the width and height and adjust your touchable areas according to these height and width variables by employing them in your css positioning.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on positioning and render my component's based on Platform.

```js
Platform.OS === `ios` ?
    <Card
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate(`detail`, {
          "id": `${item.pk}`
        });
      }}
      style={{ "marginBottom": 20 }}>
      <Card.Cover source={{ "uri": `${item.img_url}` }} />
      <Card.Actions>
        <Card.Title title={item.name} subtitle="Card Subtitle" right={Beer} />
      </Card.Actions>
    </Card> :
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate(`detail`, {
          "id": `${item.pk}`
        });
      }}
    >
      <Card style={{ "marginBottom": 20 }}>
        <Card.Cover source={{ "uri": `${item.img_url}` }} />
        <Card.Actions>
          <Card.Title title={item.name} subtitle="Card Subtitle" right={Beer} />
        </Card.Actions>
      </Card>
    </TouchableOpacity>;
```